# How to pass dynamic fields and values using mybatis 3

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

I am new to Java and mybatis3. On a project I am using mybatis3..

say I have database table named "t". There are several columns.

In the project I will send a hashmap (contains 2 ArrayList of key, value) to mapper.xml. From there it will get 2 array contain keys of columns names, and values of columns...

I want to inset into that table... by that, I think I will able to dynamically insert data and partially update some column data... with update... but getting sql syntax error...

My existing code of mapper.xml

```
<insert id="createNews" parameterType="map" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="id">
  INSERT INTO t
    <foreach item="key" collection="Key" index="index" open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{key}
    </foreach>
    VALUES
    <foreach item="value" collection="Value" index="index" open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{value}
    </foreach>
  ;
</insert>
```

partial error stackTrace....

```
### Error updating database.  Cause:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''name'
     ) 
    VALUES
     (  
        'some value'
    ' at line 3
```

But when I hard code the column name its working correctly... How can I insert dynamically...

Note: I googled, but unable to find... I don't want to use any pojo or annotation... thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you post the code(structure and the content) of your HashMap? You can also set your MyBatis logging level to show the query that is generated. http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/logging.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure, but I'll take a shot. When you use `#{key}`, MyBatis puts extra `''` around it if it is a `String`, `Date` etc. If you give your column names with a variable you need to use direct `String` replacement which is `${key}`.

The error log says something like `...right syntax to use near ''name') VALUES ('some value'...`

Can you try

```
<insert id="createNews" parameterType="map" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="id">
  INSERT INTO t
    <foreach item="key" collection="Key" index="index" open="(" separator="," close=")">
        ${key}
    </foreach>
    VALUES
    <foreach item="value" collection="Value" index="index" open="(" separator="," close=")">
        #{value}
    </foreach>
</insert>
```

Comment: Many many thanks... it's working... I tried lot of things... you saved me... thanks once again...How can I missed the "String Substitution" section from the documentation...my bad..